# Show Transformed Chi Square Variable is Approximately Standard Normal for large df

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, chi-squared-distribution, delta-method

Given that $X$ is a random variable having a Chi-Square Distribution with degrees of freedom $v$ and that $\frac{(X-v)}{(2v)^{1/2}}$ is standard normal for large $v$, then show that $(2X)^{1/2} - (2v)^{1/2}$ is standard normal for large $v$.

Having a hard time showing this algebraically. In a previous part of this question we showed that $P\left((2Y)^{1/2}-(2v)^{1/2} < k\right) = P\left(\frac{Y-v}{(2v)^{1/2}} < k + \frac{k^2}{2(2v)^{1/2}}\right)$.  I'm assuming this connects to the answer but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

This is an application of the [Delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method).

First, since $X \sim \mathcal{Chi-squared}(\nu)$, which is the distribution of a sum of squares of $\nu$ independent standard normal variates, by the CLT (central limit theorem)
$$ \frac{X-\nu}{\sqrt{2\nu}} \stackrel{D}{\to} \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$
Then let $f(x) =\sqrt{2x}$ and write the above as an approximation
$$ X-\nu \stackrel{a}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2= 2\nu) $$
and  by the delta method
$$ f(X) - f(\nu) \stackrel{a}{\sim}  \mathcal{N}(0, 2\nu \cdot (f'(\nu))^2 )$$
and by evaluating the derivative this becomes
$$ \sqrt{2X} - \sqrt{2\nu} \stackrel{a}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$

Comment: Good posts need to be upvoted.